# should destructive functions extend their classes?

Tags: ruby, algorithm, oop

I'm implementing some stuff from [CLRS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Introduction_to_Algorithms), and the `partition()` algorithm is causing me a little concern. It's implied (from the consistently vague pseudocode therein, but not stated explicitly) that `partition` should modify the array it's passed, and return a related scalar value:

```
PARTITION(A, p, r)
1 x = A[r]
2 i = p -1
3 for j = p to r - 1
4 if A[j] <= x
5   i = i + 1
6   swap A[i], A[j] 
7 swap A[i+1], A[r]
8 return i + 1
```

This is easy to throw together in Ruby, but my question is, since it changes the array it's passed without returning it, should it be a class method like `array.do_stuff!()`?

```
irb(main):007:0> ary
=> [0, 3, 0, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 4, 4, 2]
irb(main):008:0> partition(ary,2,4)
=> 3
irb(main):009:0> ary
=> [0, 3, 0, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 4, 4, 2]
```

For reference, here is my code:

```
def partition(my_list, part_start, part_end, pivot = my_list[part_end])
# From CLRS p. 171
# In-place rearrangement of subarrays.


  sort_separator = part_start - 1
  for loop_ind in (part_start..part_end-1)
    if my_list[loop_ind] <= my_list[part_end]
      sort_separator += 1
      my_list[sort_separator],my_list[loop_ind] = 
        my_list[loop_ind],my_list[sort_separator]
    end
  end
  my_list[sort_separator+1],my_list[part_end] = 
    my_list[part_end],my_list[sort_separator+1]

  return(sort_separator+1)
end
```

Comment: I think in general it is ok to modify the data in a non-class method, provided that this is obvious for the user of the method. For instance, many `sort` implementations sort an array in place. However, as far as I know, CLRS is not written object-orientedly, so you cannot simply assume that their approach is always the best (their focus is on the algorithms, though, not on software engineering).

Comment: Yeah, I would be doing it differently but the assignment is to implement this and some other code that depends on it, as given.